# Problems connecting to Sql Server CE 4.0 with Sql Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-ce, ssms

I need to set up and maintain my MS Sql CE 4.0 database. I have created the 4.0 DB (with the .sdf extension) using visual studio 2010 but when I try and connect with management studio 2008 I get this error:

'Incompatible Database Version'

This is unreal is microsoft really telling me I cant use 4.0 with a management studio?

I don't really much fancy scripting everything...I need to use the studio for dev purposes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

SSMS 2008 does not support version 4.0, and never will. You can use VS 2010 SP1 with SQL Server Compact 4.0 tools (potentially in combination with htp://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com) or on of the tools listed here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html

Comment: Im confused I have now successfully create a 4.0 database and connected to it with Sql Management Studiio 2008? Any ideas Erik?

Comment: What about SSMS 2008 R2?  Does it support CE 4.0?

Comment: No, it does not, and never will